# Unable to create bucket policy for cross account write of logs in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am trying to write logs from Cloudwatch log streams to a cross account S3 bucket. While creating  bucket policy in account B, am getting the following error.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutBucketAcl",
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:getobject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ayush-test-b3245-4676/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::45097+@#%^*#:role/service-role/s3-bucket-lambda-role-uz281"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue, I want to add a Lambda role to write these logs.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFAVu.png)

Comment: Try `"Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::ayush-test-b3245-4676", "arn:aws:s3:::ayush-test-b3245-4676/*"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an answer in the comment, but I'll provide some more explanation.

In the resource section, you need to have a resource that corresponds to each of the actions you've put in the Action array. In this case, `PutBucketAcl` needs a bucket resource, while in your example, you only have a resource that corresponds to objects inside the bucket.

Also, please double-check the spelling of `s3:getobject` which should be `s3:GetObject`.